# Backup application with Web GUI

Tags: python, sqlite, backup

I have written a small backup application in python with rsync, which I can call on a linux machine from command line. The backup application saves data in a sqlite db file.

If I want to have a web interface for this, is this an own project in python, or should I integrate this GUI in the existing application? I want to call the backup script from the GUI, with different parameters. It should be possible to add entries to the sqlite db file also.
Should I use a mysql db instead of sqlite?

Comment: It's depends on you. You can use `WSGI` to implement a service.

Comment: You mean, add a wsgi interface to my backup application, and connect it with my django(?) framework website?